# Family tree design suggestions?

Tags: jquery, family-tree

I would like to design a family tree on my website.  How can this be done with jQuery or Ajax?  Any animated examples out there?

Comment: Let this be a call to action. JQFamTree! Let thee be!

Comment: if you are interested in genealogy, be aware there is move to start up a genealogy SE Q&A. Help it reach beta: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43502/genealogy-family-history?referrer=DIRpC-2QEpSJcDcQkP0RAg2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the Google Visualization API, it's well documented: http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/orgchart.html#Example

Comment: with Google Visualization API, can we have a Pop-Up on each of the node which would give more details about that node, either on mouse-over or on a click.

Comment: It seems that nodes can only be "one-to-may". You cannot be related with two parents

Answer (score 3):

The following link will be helpful to share here as i applied every logic mentioned here but none works. at last i found this solution. It helped me build professional family tree via jquery and php

[jTree Family Tree Script](http://www.bootstrapkits.com/jtree/)

Answer (score 1):

Check [www.geni.com](http://www.geni.com). They use Flash, not JavaScript, but it's nice, animated and so on.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the jQuery plugin site turned up [Arrows & Boxes](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/arrows-and-boxes).  It looks like it does what you need.  If this one doesn't work out, there are probably a dozen others to try.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [my sample](http://scienic-data.com/force-layout-british-monarch-family-tree/) created using d3.js, mobile responsive.

- Mouse scroll to zoom, draggable, with interactive tooltip
- The 'Find' button to search any family member
- 'Reset' button to reset zoom & position

Able to display difficult relationships such as multiple marriages and marriages between family members. Created using d3.js